# How to pass worktree in init function in golang using go-git package?

Tags: go

I am trying to get over the `worktree not available in a bare repository` error. So I tried implementing it using the following lines:

```
// git library to initialize git in testAppDir
                    fs := memfs.New()
                    storer := memory.NewStorage()
                    testAppDir, _ := git.Init(storer, fs)
```

But it shows a new error now: `cannot use fs (variable of type billy.Filesystem) as billy.Filesystem value in argument to git.Init: wrong type for method Chroot (have func(path string) (github.com/go-git/go-billy/v5.Filesystem, error), want func(path string) (gopkg.in/src-d/go-billy.v4.Filesystem, error))`

Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git; it's a pure Go issue. You seem to be using both `go-billy.v4.Filesystem` and `go-billy/v5.Filesystem` and trying to mix the two when they're not compatible. What exactly you should do about this depends on code you *didn't* show. See [ask] and try to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The only place I used it is during the import:  `// billy "github.com/go-git/go-billy/v5
 memfs "github.com/go-git/go-billy/v5/memfs"
 //rmc "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/config"
 "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
 "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing"
 "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object"
 "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/storage/memory" `

Comment: Edit: I changed the import version to v4 and it seems to work! Thank you!